# Undelete a post

Tags: support, migration, math-stackexchange, deleted-questions, undelete-request

Is there any possibility of undeleting a post? I know it was closed years ago as not MO level. So maybe it could be undeleted and then moved to MSE? Just because it hosts a discussion which is referenced elsewhere. Thanks

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55982/extending-a-riemannian-metric-to-one-on-k-forms

Comment: It's slightly awkward to migrate a question to another site if the question was already answered there. Is that the case?

Comment: Well the very old question of mine which referenced the deleted thread is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70938/16490, which does have an answer, and might qualify as answering the same question, although it's not completely identical. Doing a quick search on m.se i also found https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213450/16490 which has no answer.

Comment: This non-deleted question is not quite the same, but pretty close: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441829/coordinate-free-way-to-construct-inner-product-on-exterior-powers

Comment: For the benefit of users who cannot see deleted posts, here is a link to a version of that question [saved in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727141416/http://mathoverflow.net:80/questions/55982/extending-a-riemannian-metric-to-one-on-k-forms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we can easily undelete the question, actually migrating it would be impossible. We can only migrate questions which are younger than 60 days.

Given that the post had been automatically deleted over a decade ago, that is over than 60 times the 60 days limit.

Undeleting the question is likely to cause it to be deleted by the bot again. So there is little to no point in doing that.